# Extract the element from html page in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am new to R and trying to scrape the map data from the following webpage:
https://www.svk.se/en/national-grid/the-control-room/. The map is called "The flow of electricity". I am trying to scrape the capacity numbers (in blue) and the corresponding countries. So far I could not find a solution on how to find the countries' names in the HTML code and consequently scrape them.

Here is an example of data I need: [image]

Would you have any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The data is not in the table, hence we need to extract all the information individually.

Here is a way to do this using `rvest`.

```
library(rvest)
url <-'https://www.svk.se/en/national-grid/the-control-room/'

webpage <- url %>% read_html() %>%html_nodes('div.island')

tibble::tibble(country = webpage %>% html_nodes('span.country') %>% html_text(),
                watt = webpage %>% html_nodes('span.watt') %>% html_text() %>% 
                         gsub('\\s', '', .) %>% as.numeric(),
                unit = webpage %>% html_nodes('span.unit') %>% html_text())


#  country    watt unit 
#  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>
#1 SWEDEN     3761 MW   
#2 DENMARK     201 MW   
#3 NORWAY     2296 MW   
#4 FINLAND    1311 MW   
#5 ESTONIA     632 MW   
#6 LATVIA      177 MW   
#7 LITHUANIA  1071 MW
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks a lot for your answer. I meant the figures from the map though. So, each individual flow from one country to another. Should look something like FI > EE  1031MW. I cannot find the "FI>EE" element in html. Regards.

Comment: I don't see anything like `FI > EE 1031MW.` on the map. There are values like `€6.89` on the map.

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot in the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

The flow data comes from an API call so you need to make an additional xhr (to an url you can find in the network tab via dev tools ) to get this data. You don't need to specify values for the timestamp (`Ticks`) and random (`rnd`) params in the querystring.

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://www.svk.se/Proxy/Proxy/?a=http://driftsdata.statnett.no/restapi/PhysicalFlowMap/GetFlow?Ticks=&rnd=')
```

As a dataframe:

```
library(jsonlite)
library (plyr)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://www.svk.se/Proxy/Proxy/?a=http://driftsdata.statnett.no/restapi/PhysicalFlowMap/GetFlow?Ticks=&rnd=')

df <- ldply (data, data.frame)
```